# How to align paragraph vertically and horizontally center in div

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to align my paragraph tag text vertically centre.

```css
.footer-container {
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 100px 0 100px 0;
}

.copyright {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.copyright-derrick {
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 25px;
  bottom: -80px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Footer -->

<section class="footer">
  <div class="footer-container">
    <p class="copyright">Copyright &copy; 2022 Jessica Smith</p>
    <p class="copyright-derrick">Created by Derrick Ogole Web Services</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

My code pen: https://codepen.io/derrickogole/pen/rNxbaaK

As you see, the text "Copyright...." is higher up vertically. However, I would like it vertically center so it's both horizontally and vertically centre.

Comment: I edited your pen, check [this](https://codepen.io/Asef00/pen/poaOxWe) out.

Comment: I still want to keep "Created by Derrick...." in the bottom right corner. How is that possible?

Comment: @AsefHossini ......so the copyright message stays centre aligned while the "Created by...." goes to the bottom right corner. I made the code simpler if that helps. Check out my pen: https://codepen.io/derrickogole/pen/rNxbaaK